# Automatic suspend gets triggered too early when running on battery

Tags: suspend, 17.10, power-management, battery

I'm currently using Ubuntu 17.10 (artful) with the Gnome window maanger.
Power options are currently configured as:

**Suspend & Power Button** > **Automatic suspend**

- When on battery power: ON
- Delay: 2 hours

However, after 15 minutes inactivity, my laptop suspends. What could be the problem the 'delay' configuration is ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried to re-set the value in the drop-down list? I mean setting to something other, and after that resetting it to 2 hours?

As I noticed if there is some other value set deep inside the settings (dconf -> /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-inactive-battery-timeout) then 2 hours gets displayed.

Comment: I tried re-setting the value in the GUI, with no luck.

The other setting you mentioned (through dconf) -> the value was set to 300 seconds. So this might be indeed the reason why it sleeps so early. I adapted the value and I'll keep you up to date if I bump into this problem or not.

Comment: Your solution works! I accepted your answer! Thanks!